# passing arguments to included module's method

Tags: ruby

want to integrate this module into my Rails app for separating event items in the view based on the past/present test, but first want to understand how it's supposed to work. I looked through related threads on here and Well-Grounded Rubyist chapter on modules and didn't find a definitive answer on how to do this. here are my doodles:

```
module BeforeOrAfter
  require "date"
  def initialize
    @datetime = DateTime.new
    @past = []
    @future = []
  end

  def before_or_after
    if datetime < DateTime.now
      @past << datetime
    else
      @future << datetime
    end
  end
end

class BoA
  include BeforeOrAfter
end

b = BoA.new
b.before_or_after(2016, 04, 06, 03, 01, 00)

print b.past
```

the error that I get is `in`before_or_after': wrong number of arguments (6 for 0) (ArgumentError)`

Comment: You defined `before_or_after` that takes no arguments, but you gave it 6 arguments when calling it.

Comment: moved further down to `in 'before_or_after': undefined local variable or method 'datetime' for #<BoA:0x007fa41a9cb6a0> (NameError)`

Comment: What is `datetime`? A local variable? An instance method? Have you defined it?

Comment: You're supposed to define #before_or_after like this: `def before_or_after(datetime)` and call it afterwards like this: `b.before_or_after(DateTime.new(2016, 04, 06, 03, 01, 00))`

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim thank you! and how can I get the `past` array to print? I get the undefined method error when trying b.past

Comment: @sivanes @past is a instance variable not exposed to the outside world. You must define a getter in order to be able retrieve it. `att_reader :past` will generate a getter for you.

Comment: @AlexandreAngelim perfect! been a few months since writing Ruby, it's starting to come back now.